# Is it possible to filter test files and individual tests with different patterns in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

According to the [nose documentation](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#options), the `--match` option sets the pattern for *all* test discovery:

> Files, directories, function names, and class names that match this
>   regular expression are considered tests. Default: (?:\b|_)[Tt]est
>   [NOSE_TESTMATCH]

I often find that I would prefer to use separate matches for files, directories, function names and class names, not one pattern that has to match all of them. As an example, using this test suite:

```
import unittest

class CoolBeansTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testCool(self):
        self.assertEqual(cool_function_takes_forever(), 7)

    def testBeans(self):
        inst = MyCoolBeansClass()
        self.assertEqual(inst.getBeanz(), "CoolBeans")

class WarmBeansTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testWarm(self):
        self.assertEqual(warm_function_takes_forever(), 21)

    def testBeans(self):
        inst = MyWarmBeansClass()
        self.assertEqual(inst.getBeanz(), "WarmBeans")
```

I might want to run all tests caled `testBeans`, but use the standard test discovery patterns for everything except functions. Other than enumerating all tests, or piping in some `grep` expression to `nosetests`, is there a way to run all *tests* matching a pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nose provides a way to *change the built-in test selection logic by making a custom `Selector`*:

- [Using a Custom Selector](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_selector_plugin/selector_plugin.html#using-a-custom-selector)

In your case, you would just need to make your own `Selector` class based on `nose.selector.Selector` and override the `wantMethod` method:

```
from nose.selector import Selector

class MySelector(Selector):
    def wantMethod(self, method):
        # custom logic here - returns True/False
```

FYI, all of the `want*` methods of a [built-in `Selector`](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/716d822d43db30195f795daa9fd71d54e682ec0c/nose/selector.py#L29) use `matches` function that is using the configured `--match` value which is `(?:\b|_)[Tt]est` by default.

Also see how the [`wantMethod` is implemented in `nose.selector.Selector`](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/716d822d43db30195f795daa9fd71d54e682ec0c/nose/selector.py#L159).

After preparing your selector, you should then inject it into the test loader by making a plugin:

```
>>> from nose.plugins import Plugin
>>> class UseMySelector(Plugin):
...     enabled = True
...     def configure(self, options, conf):
...         pass # always on
...     def prepareTestLoader(self, loader):
...         loader.selector = MySelector(loader.config)
```

Comment: This more or less worked. I'll add some code later to show exactly how I did it with this approach.